# Prevent Container from Filling All Space in ReorderableListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a [`ReorderableListView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html) that contains a list of elements (code below) and but when you long press the element to drag to reorder, it expands the `Container` to fill the whole screen. Image below:

[image]

Here is what it looks like when it is not being long pressed:

[image]

I want the code to still allow the `Container` to expand because it needs to expand when errors show up on the `TextFormFields`. Here is my `Container`:

```dart
Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Text(
              'Drill Name',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Color(0x70000000)),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          TextFormField(),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Text(
              'Shots',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Color(0x70000000)),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Somehow I want to prevent my `Container` from expanding when being reordered, but allow it to expand if there is error message for my `TextFormField` (e.g. "Drill name cannot be empty").

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured it out or not, the solution is to add the following line to Column():

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min
```